# how to query mysql match must contain a and b boolean

Tags: mysql

I have a problem here. i would like to perform a search that the field must contain both words of the keyword, for example i would like to search "Bridgs 185"
Lets say i have a table like this

```
id |  NamaBarang
    -----------------------------
    1    Bridgs TURANZA 185
    2    Bridgs POTENZA 185
    3    Bridgs TURANZA 175
    4    Bridgs B250-B250
```

And i have query is like this

```
SELECT namaBarang FROM `barang` WHERE match(namaBarang) AGAINST ('+Bridgs* +185*')
```

And i also try

```
SELECT namaBarang FROM `barang` WHERE match(namaBarang) AGAINST ('+Bridgs +185')
```

But it always get returns all of the table before

My question is.. how to get the result that must contains "Bridgs" And "185" When i search using keyword "Bridgs 185" And the result should be like this..

```
id |  NamaBarang
-----------------------------
1    Bridgs TURANZA 185
2    Bridgs POTENZA 185
```

Thanks before...

Comment: next time, split the single column in multiple columns and concatenate the results only through selects and concat()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
where namaBarang like 'Bridgs%185'
```

Comment: % at the last would match any length of text, so `Bridgs%185%` would match 'Bridgs TEXT 18576 ABC' or 'Bridgs TEXT 185XX ABC'. If this is acceptable given your dataset then your edit would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
SELECT namaBarang FROM `barang` 
WHERE match(namaBarang) AGAINST ('+Bridgs +185' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```